# Angular 1 ngMouseleave for touchscreens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, touch, directive

I have an Angular 1/Javascript program that runs in Chrome in Kiosk mode. This application is used with a Touchscreen only.

We have a set of buttons which control a HTTP camera, to zoom in/out and adjust the angle. The problem is that when a user clicks on a button, for example zoom, he holds the touch while dragging down (away from the button).

Therefor the camera keeps turning/zooming, even while the user is not pressing the button anymore. It does not detect the user leaving the button.

I want to catch this behavior by detecting when his finger leaves the button, and then stopping the command.

I've come up with the following code to check if the user is moving his/her finger while pressing the button, if the user moves a lot the movement stops.

Directive:

```
    app.directive("ngTouchmove", function () {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.bind('touchstart', onTouchStart);

            function onTouchStart(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $element.bind('touchmove', onTouchMove);
                $element.bind('touchend', onTouchEnd);
            };

            function onTouchMove(event) {
                var method = $element.attr('ng-touchmove');
                $scope.$event = event;
                $scope.$apply(method);
            };

            function onTouchEnd(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $element.unbind('touchmove', onTouchMove);
                $element.unbind('touchend', onTouchEnd);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
var amountMoved = 0;
$scope.onTouchmove = function(source, command) {
    amountMoved ++;
    if (amountMoved > 10) {
        amountMoved = 0;
        $scope.mouseUp(source, command)
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that when you re-arrange your finger slightly while touching the button, the command stops. I can set the amountMoved check number higher, but this makes it less accurate.

How could I approach this problem? 
Should I make a touch-leave directive? If so, what could be a good start on implementing this?

Comment: Implement a 'debounce' so that you don't unbind the events immediately.

Comment: Minimize the amount of DOM manipulation done in JavaScript. Only bind event handlers when the element is added and only unbind event handlers when the element is removed.